# Printing out all my posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Does anybody know if there is a way that I could print out all of my answers and or questions on E&U without going to each individual page and printing it off?

Also, do we want there to be a print button on pages? I quite often want to print out other peoples answers. It's a bind having to select them etc.

Comment: There is no way I'm aware of, other than writing a custom script. As for printing: I haven't printed anything, except in cases where I'm forced, in over half a decade (other than very lengthy papers).

Comment: This might be a good meta.stackexchange.com question...if it's not a duplicate. With a little tweaking, the accepted answer for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content might suggest a way.

Comment: Maybe not on the page, but somewhere in the settings...

Answer (score 1):

> This might be a good meta.stackexchange.com question...if it's not a duplicate. With a little tweaking, the accepted answer for [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/) might suggest a way. – JEL May 26 at 6:13